# Mutiplethread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions

I have a interview question! The question is "now, you have only one product in your database (database for a store) but there are 2 difference request to buy this product. Do you have any idea for this problem?". I think this problem about Mutilthread(in JAVA) or Transaction(in Database). Can some one give me a simple example to handle it?

Sorry about my bad English and thank you so much !

Comment: Ideally this would be handled by your database, not your application. The database should lock the record during an update. [MySql does it automatically](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-row-level-locking).

Comment: i also think that but can you give me a example?

Comment: If you use MySql, you shouldn't have to do anything different than normal. Are you asking how to write an `UPDATE` statement in SQL?

Comment: No, i can do that!  But how about difference database like Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend !

Comment: It looks like [Oracle also does it automatically](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502). I don't know about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL like below:

```
update stock = stock - 1 where productId = prodcutId and stock - 1 >= 0;
```

When this SQL is executed, it will return update number. if return value > 0, execute success, else execute fail.